# How effective are bleach or ozonated water at killing covid19?

Tags: covid-19

I'm wondering if cheaper alternatives are as effective in daily cleanliness of surfaces.

Answer (score 3):

> Diluted household bleach solutions can be used if appropriate for the surface. Follow manufacturer’s instructions for application and proper ventilation. Check to ensure the product is not past its expiration date. Never mix household bleach with ammonia or any other cleanser. Unexpired household bleach will be effective against coronaviruses when properly diluted.

Prepare a bleach solution by mixing:

5 tablespoons (1/3rd cup) bleach per gallon of water or

4 teaspoons bleach per quart of water

https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/prepare/cleaning-disinfection.html

Answer (score 1):

There's no evidence that ozonated water is of any use for killing COVID-19 or any other disease organism.  [Gaseous ozone is effective as a disinfectant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozone#Applications_2), but it requires concentrations far higher than can be dissolved in water (or can be tolerated by humans -- if you were to step into a room being treated with ozone, you'd die of lung damage in short order).

[The EPA has a list of cleaners known to be able to kill COVID-19](https://www.epa.gov/pesticide-registration/list-n-disinfectants-use-against-sars-cov-2).  Common household cleaning agents on that list include concentrated ethanol (70% or higher concentration -- vodka won't cut it), hydrogen peroxide, isopropyl alcohol (listed as "isopropanol"), and chlorine bleach (listed as "sodium hypochlorite").  Note that a quick wipe won't do the job: you need to keep the surface wetted for between ten seconds and ten minutes, depending on what you're using.